# How to track the ad name of the ad that the user click on in flurry analytics?

Tags: flurry, flurry-analytics

How to track the ad name of the ad that the user clicks on in flurry analytics?

Comment: Are you showing ads through the Flurry SDK, and want to track details of which ads are clicked on?

Comment: no, i m showing ads on some publisher website and want to see in the attribution report not only the campaign name but also the ad name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flurry User Acquisitions Analytics only shows the clicks and installs on the campaign level, it is not possible to view on a more granular level.